# Get different data from a modal with database id

Tags: php, jquery, sql

I have brought in data from the database using mysqli_fetch_array();
I put the data from the database and insert it into a table

so the tbody looks like this:

```
<tbody>
   <?php 
     $query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM project");
     $index = 1;
     while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {?>
         <tr>
            <td><?php echo $index; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data['project_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data['client_name']; ?></td>
            <td><a href="#"</a>View</td>
            <td style="text-align:center">
              <a data-id="$data['id']" href="dashboard.php?remove_project=<?php echo $data['id']; ? 
                  >"><i style="color: red" class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <?php $index++; }; ?>
</tbody>
```

I want a situation where when I click view, a modal pops up showing me data exactly from that Id, the goal is to click on the view and see a modal or a registered user. So I want to click on **View** and then the modal shows me data from that click, and when I click another **View** on the table, it shows me different data.

Comment: I've seen this done often before. Have you managed to find anything and tried it?

Comment: Btw, I don't see you echoing `<?php $index++;`. Edit: same thing for `<a data-id="$data['id']"`.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I haven't found anything, my level of php is still at 50% not fully a pro on this, I saw something like that but it didn't work

Comment: the data-id="$data['id'] is a mistake, the link works fine to remove the data from the table and for the database, it's the view I need

Comment: I've still not found a way, I don't want to use AJAX, the example you gave uses AJAX, just PHP, lol